# Why some nginx configs are missing the http block?

Tags: nginx

According to the nginx beginner's guide:

> Serving Static Content
>
> An important web server task is serving out
> files (such as images or static HTML pages). You will implement an
> example where, depending on the request, files will be served from
> different local directories: /data/www (which may contain HTML files)
> and /data/images (containing images). This will require editing of the
> configuration file and setting up of a server block inside the http
> block with two location blocks.

But most of the nginx conf files are missing this `http { ... }` part.

I can't find anything on the document describing about it.

Is this `http { ... }` block just optional? When should I use/omit it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`http {}` block is essential for serving HTTP and is mandatory for it. The thing is, it's defined in the main `nginx.conf` configuration file, not in the includes. So includes only define a `server {}` block, at least one for each vhost, and they are actually included **inside** the `http {}` block in the main config file.

Comment: Thanks, it's my fault to ignore the parent conf file.